# How can we fliter data from header's TextInput on onChangeText in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have custom header which has TextInput for searching in StackNavigator.How can i get result on **onChangeText** of TextInput on particular class, 
  here is demo:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 TABS: {
    screen: TabNav,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        header:
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#025281', flexDirection: 
         'row', alignItems: 'center', height: 60 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>
              <Image source={require(back_arrowimg)} style={{ 
                width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain' }}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    <TextInput
              style={{ color: 'white', paddingLeft: 15, }}
              type='text'
              placeholder={headerTitle}
              onChangeText={this.loadUsers}
            />
          </View>,
      }
    }   },

  [ConstFile.SCREEN_TITLES.WELCOME_SEARCH]: {
    screen: WELCOMESEARCH,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }   }, } )
```

Comment: and where you want to show results ?

Comment: I want results on "TabNav" screen which has multiple tabs.I just want to get live onChangeText value for current tab.

Answer (score 0):

from `navigationOption` you can not do anything to other screen,

so what you can do is, move your header code into another file and use it as component in TabNav

something like this,
let say Header.js

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#025281', flexDirection: 
         'row', alignItems: 'center', height: 60 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>
          <Image source={require(back_arrowimg)} style={{ 
                width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain' }}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TextInput
              style={{ color: 'white', paddingLeft: 15, }}
              type='text'
              placeholder={headerTitle}
              onChangeText={this.props.loadUsers} // see this change
            />
</View>
```

and in your TabNav.js use header as component,

```
<Header 
  loadUsers={(...your params)=>{
    //do your necessary stuffs to display data in this file
  }) />
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have to use loadUsers() method in tabs, i only want to know that how can change text of screen onChangeText of TextInput of Header which is placed in createStackNavigator

Comment: @civanimahida I don't think there is any method that can directly change data from StackNavigator to a particular screen. You need to have header in screen.

Comment: i can't set headers in tab pages with "navigationOptions". Actually I want to search in multiple tabs like Instagram.Any other way for searching in multiple tabs?

Comment: Well, Instagram has one particular tab for search is you have seen it. And for this you don't need to put header in `navigationOption` but as a normal component that will render in your tabbar screen.